# Entity Framework Core: cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Database in my project includes table with cycle link:

[image]

Here's the entity class with fluent configuration:

```
public class ReportFolder
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentFolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual ReportFolder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ReportFolder> ChildFolders { get; set; }
}

public class ReportFolderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ReportFolder>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ReportFolder> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Property(c => c.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

        builder.HasOne(c => c.ParentFolder)
            .WithMany(c => c.ChildFolders)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentFolderId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

        builder.HasIndex(c => c.Name);
    }
}
```

**Problem:** I catch error when trying to update database via migration:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ReportFolders_ReportFolders_ParentFolderId' on table 'ReportFolders' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: .Change `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull` to `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict`

Comment: Yeah, I think where is no way to use SetNull behavior

Comment: Both `Cascade` and `SetNull` are **cascade** delete referential actions, hence suffer the *cycles or multiple cascade paths* problem. You can simply skip `OnDelete` configuration which will leave the default option for optional relationships `ClientSetNull`, or use `Restrict` as already suggested. In either cases, you have to handle delete parent with children programmatically, otherwise the database constraint will stop you.